# Is there a way to use bootstrap modal dialog to both take user to internal anchor link and to dismiss it simultaneously?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal dialog that I want to use as a 'quick navigation' menu. The modal dialog comes up as expected, and dismisses as expected, but does not take the user to the link within the page. If I remove data-dismiss="modal" then the user is taken to the right link, however the modal dialog remains. Is there a way to do both?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Large Modal</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Large Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <a href="#internalLink" data-dismiss="modal">internal link</a>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div style="padding-top:800px">spacer</div>
    <div id="internalLink">target</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this script and adding the class 'nav-btn' to any links on the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-btn").click(function(){
        $("#menuModal").modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't you have a problem with focus ? I mean after browser scrolls down to target, doesn't it jump back to the button?